# LTRIM and RTRIM Truncating Floating Point Number

Tags: sql-server

I am experiencing what I would describe as entirely unexpected behaviour when I pass a `float` value through either `LTRIM` or `RTRIM`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(MyCol float null)

INSERT MyTable
values (11.7333335876465)

SELECT  MyCol, 
        RTRIM(LTRIM(MyCol)) lr, 
        LTRIM(MyCol) l, 
        RTRIM(MyCol) r 
FROM    MyTable
```

Which gives the following results:

```
MyCol              | lr      | l       | r
--------------------------------------------
11.7333335876465   | 11.7333 | 11.7333 | 11.7333
```

I have observed the same behaviour on SQL Server 2014 and 2016.

Now, my understanding is that `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` should just strip off white space from a value - not cast it/truncate it.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

---

Just to explain the background to this. I am generating SQL queries using the properties of a set of C# POCOs (the results will be used to generate an MD5 hash that will then be compared to an equivalent value from an Oracle table) and for convenience was wrapping every column with LTRIM/RTRIM.

Comment: Looks like it is cast to a string to fit the function requirements. Nothing weird about it

Comment: why are you trying to trim white space off something of `float` datatype anyway? There will never be any. This can only apply to string representations.

Comment: So you get unexpected behaviour when use a string function with a float value. Then dont do it.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I've added an explanation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use format() instead

```
Declare @F float = 11.7333335876465
Select format(@F,'#.##############')
```

Returns

```
11.7333335876465
```